# Delete all items from a list

Tags: c#, list

I want to delete all the elements from my list:

```
foreach (Session session in m_sessions)
{
    m_sessions.Remove(session);
}
```

In the last element I get an exception: UnknownOperation.

Anyone know why?

how should I delete all the elements? It is ok to write something like this:

```
m_sessions = new List<Session>();
```

Comment: `m_Sessions.Clear()` ?

Comment: Are you sure you get all the way to the last element, I would think you would get an exception on the first attempt to modify a list which is used for iteration

Comment: It is strange that you are not getting the concurrent modification exception.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you are right, I had only one element so I got it on the first and on the last

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You aren't allowed to modify a `List<T>` whilst iterating over it with `foreach`. Use `m_sessions.Clear()` instead.

Whilst you could write `m_sessions = new List<Session>()` this is not a good idea. For a start it is wasteful to create a new list just to clear out an existing one. What's more, if you have other references to the list then they will continue to refer to the old list. Although, as @dasblinkenlight points out, `m_sessions` is probably a private member and it's unlikely you have other references to the list. No matter, `Clear()` is the canonical way to clear a `List<T>`.

Comment: Exactly, on with a list iterator can you safely modify a list while traversing over it.  Iterators know of the previous / next nodes and are designed for modifications.  Standard for loop macros and while loops do not.

Comment: +1 However, assuming that `m_` stands for *member*, and that it is also private, having other references to `m_sessions` would indicate problems at a deeper level.

Comment: Why would m_sessions = new .. ; (or m_sessions = null for that matter, wich is what I am reading into this)  actually clear the list?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe No, the old list would not be cleared, but `m_sessions` would be referring to a different list, a new instance.

Comment: Ok, -"wasteful to create a new list just to clear out an existing one. ". Clear out = Get out of sight.

Answer (score 14):

Never, ever, modify a collection that is being iterated on with `foreach`. Inserting, deleting, and reordering are no-nos. You may, however, modify the `foreach` variable (`session` in this case).

In this case, use

```
m_sessions.Clear();
```

and eliminate the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m_sessions.RemoveRange ( 0 , m_sessions.Count() );
```